# Send raw json HTTP request for an API call in Yii 1.x.x

Tags: php, json, api, yii, frameworks

I asked a similar question earlier, in a nutshell I have an API application that takes json requests and outputs an json response.

For instance here is one of the requests that I need to test out, how can I use this json object with my testing to emulate a 'real request'

```
{
  "request" : {
       "model" : {
            "code" : "PR92DK1Z"
    }
}
```

The response is straightforward (this bit has been done).

From other users on here this is the optimised method using Yii to do this, I am just unsure how to emulate the json request - e.g essentially send a JSON HTTP request, can anyone assist on how to do this?

```
public function actionMyRequest() {
   // somehow add my json request... 

   $requestBody = Yii::app()->request->getRawBody();
   $parsedRequest = CJSON::decode($requestBody);
   $code = $parsedRequest["request"]["model"]["code"];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand if you want your app to send an http request and get the result or at the opposite receive a http request

I answered for the first assumption, I'll change my answer if you want the other

For me the best way to send an HTTP request is to use Guzzle http client.

This is not a yii extension, but you can use third party libraries with yii.

Here's an example from [Guzzle page](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();           // 200
echo $res->getHeader('content-type'); // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
```

So in your case you could do something like:

```
public function actionMyRequest() {
   $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
   $res = $client->get('https://api.your-url.com/'); 
   $requestBody = $res->getBody();

   $parsedRequest = CJSON::decode($requestBody);
   $code = $parsedRequest["request"]["model"]["code"];
}
```